# How to run selenium tests in headless mode on Mac using Webdriver with firefox 17.0.1

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xvfb

How to run Automated selenium tests in Mac OS 10.8 with firefox 17.0.1 using Xvfb(X-virtual frame buffer)
Anyone help me regarding this configuration.

Comment: check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25451133/xvfb-run-on-os-x)

Comment: This question is extremely broad - can you update the question with details about what you have tried, and what part is not working?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think such old Firefox version is still relevant. But for those who still want to use old Firefox versions - take a look at [Selenoid](http://github.com/aerokube/selenoid) project. This is a lightweight Selenium-compatible server coming with a set of prebuilt Docker [images](http://aerokube.com/selenoid/latest/#_browser_image_information) for all Firefox versions starting with 3.6. All images include Xvfb inside, so this solution is completely headless.

Answer (score 0):

Will you try adding this option to your binary of Firefox if you are using
binary of Firefox.

**binary.addArguments("-headless");**

If you are not using binary and using driver as new Firefox driver then

```
 FirefoxOptions fireFoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
 fireFoxOptions.addArguments("-headless");
 DesiredCapabilities firefoxcapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();  
 capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY,fireFoxOptions);
 WebDriver firefoxdriver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxcapabilities);
```

Also, this is a very old version of Firefox I will prefer upgrading the version if you don't have any restrictions upgrading it.